# Terraria mobile key mold farm in the ocean

Tags: terraria-mobile

Hey I'm trying to make a jungle farm for keymolds in the ocean but the only thing spawning are shaks and jelly fish. I have over 200 jungle blocks and the music is playing. Is it glitched on mobile?

Comment: I would not think it is glitched, are you sure you are not simply unlucky or it hasn't dropped yet? The drop rate is very low at 1 in 2500.

Comment: My problem is that arapaima won't spawn so I can't really farm out there in the ocean with out them

Comment: you don't need any specific enemies to get the Jungle Key to drop - it can drop from any enemy as long as you are in the Jungle biome when you kill the enemy

Comment: Why in the ocean?